# Android Multiple Image downloading using multipart response and displaying in grid view

Tags: android, image, picasso, multipart

I have a business use case where we need to download multiple files from the server in a single request where files will be sent back as multipart response. Once downloaded display in a grid view. So far we have the request/response working but android failing on out of memory issue sometime (based one device). On some device it works and on some it doesn't. I googled for the possible solution and finding some of the open source libraries like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Most of examples from these libraries are around downloading multiple images using multiple requests.

I am thinking once I download images as a part of single multipart response, I should store it somewhere and then use one of the library to in order to load it in image view within Grid View.

Can anyone recommend anything here?

Comment: How big are these images? You should probably reduce their size on the server.

Comment: about upto 1mb per image and total 5mb worth of images

Comment: They will have to be in memory in any case, so that they can be displayed. What is the design of the program, will the images be needed again?

Comment: Design is ..user clicks on attachment link....app sends request to server...server finds attachments..sends all as part of multi part response...app then needs to display all images on a device in scrollable grid view..User will have an opportunity to choose individual image and edit the image(crop, rotate etc.)..user can also delete image...at the end user will click on save button to upload all images back to server...App sends all images back to server using multi part request.

Comment: As so, the images will have to be in the memory the whole time anyways, but it still pays to cache it yourself, in case of user exits app. Just save each file as it's  downloaded to the cache directory. When finished downloading, load each file to image.